# React-Select Async is showing error when my search result is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to implement an async react-select dropdown where if the user types in the dropdown, there will be search results returned from the search API. With my code it works fine if what I searched has results, but if there's no results, I will get the `props.options.map is not a function` error.

What can I do to handle this error when there are no results?

**Error**

[image]

This is what the API returns if there's any related results:

[image]

And this is what the API will return if there's no result found:

[image]

**SearchUserDropdown.js**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
import makeAnimated from 'react-select/animated';

const SearchUserDropdown = ({ setGroupMembers }) => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('') 
    
    //get animated components wrapper
    const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();

    const loadOptions = async () => {
        const res = await fetch(`https://example-api.com/search_user?value=${query}`);
        const data = await res.json();
        const results = data.Result;
        return results;
    };

    return (
        <AsyncSelect
            cacheOptions
            isMulti
            components={animatedComponents}
            getOptionLabel={(e) => e.fullname}
            getOptionValue={(e) => e.empId}
            loadOptions={loadOptions}
            onInputChange={(value) => setQuery(value)}
            onChange={(value) => setGroupMembers(value)}
        />
    );
};

export default SearchUserDropdown;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit your `loadOptions` function to return an empty array instead of a string in case of an empty result:

```
const loadOptions = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://example-api.com/search_user?value=${query}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    const results = data.Result;
    if (results === "No result found.") {
        // Empty result, return an empty array instead of a string
        return [];
    }
    return results;
};
```